# Can anyone help me with this question on vibrational modes of free base porphyrin (C20H14N4)?

Tags: physical-chemistry, spectroscopy, molecular-structure, ir-spectroscopy

> **4 a.** The structure of free-base porphyrin $(\ce{H2P}$, chemical formula: $\ce{C20H14N4})$ is shown below. Given that this molecule belongs to the $D_\mathrm{2h}$ point group (character table given above) identify the symmetries (*irreps*) for all the vibrational modes of this planar polyatomic molecule;
>
> [image: Free base porphyrin]
>
> (i) Identify the number of vibrational modes in $\ce{H2P}$. *[3 marks]*
> (ii) Work out the reducible representation for the vibrational modes. *[6 marks]*
> (iii) Use the reduction formula to identify the (*irreps*) for all the vibrational modes. *[6 marks]*
> (iv) Identify which of the vibrational modes are Raman-active and which are IR-active. *[4 marks]*

In particular I'm getting stuck with figuring out the unmoved atoms when applying symmetry operations. I know i need to calculate gamma vib in order to use the reduction formula but I cannot picture how to apply the symmetry operations to calculate unmoved atoms for each symmetry class (aside from E) because it is a more complicated structure than I'm used to dealing with (h20, benzene etc)

Comment: One thing to think about in the question: is the free base porphyrin really D2h symmetric?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you rotate the molecule by $45^\circ$, the rotation axes will fall on the cartesian axes $x, y, x$, and the mirror planes will be at $xy, yz, xz$.

[image]

Now, you can see that the NH groups are unaffected by rotation about $y$ or reflection on $yz$, the deprotonated N groups by rotation about $x$ or reflection on $xz$, and all the atoms by reflection on $xy$. You can ignore the position of the double bonds because it is an aromatic system.

Whenever an atoms lies on a mirror plane or a pure rotation axis, its position will be unaffected by the symmetry operation.